# Bash Script File Descriptor echo

Tags: bash, shell, sh, file-descriptor

```
echo: write error: Bad file descriptor
```

Throughout my code (through several bash scripts) I encounter this error.  It happens when I'm trying to write or append to a (one) file.

```
LOGRUN_SOM_MUT_ANA=/Volumes/.../logRUN_SOMATIC_MUT_ANA
```

I use the absolute path for this variable and I use the same file for each script that is called.  The file has a bunch of lines just like this.  I use the import '.' on each script to get it.

```
echo "debug level set for $DEBUG_LEVEL" >> ${LOGRUN_SOM_MUT_ANA}
```

Worth noting:

- It typically happens AFTER the FIRST time I write to it.
- I read about files 'closing' themselves and yielding this error
- I am using the above line in one script, and then calling another script.

I'd be happy to clarify anything.

[image: launch script]

[image: errors]

[image: The second script, called from the first]

Comment: could you post more code? how do you define `$LOGRUN_SOM_MUT_ANA`?

Comment: and is there any chance that the value of `LOGRUN_SOM_MUT_ANA` is changing to something with a space in it? Good luck.

Comment: Why would a space do anything?  What would that do?

Comment: Can you give us the full value of LOGRUN_SOM_MUT_ANA? Also, try echoing the value of LOGRUN_SOM_MUT_ANA before each of your redirected echo statements appending to the file just to be sure that you are in fact appending to the file you expect in all cases.

Comment: The full value of LOGRUN_SOM_MUT_ANA is: /Volumes/PhilDrive_EMS/TestDec7/snv_postprocess/logRUN_SOMATIC_MUT_ANA

Comment: I actually had a thought.  The drive is encrypted with this Credant software.  Would that affect it?  I'll run it tomorrow completely unencrypted and report back.

Comment: Please don't post *pictures* of your code here; it makes things much harder to work with (and less searchable, and less accessible).  It's very easy to post code samples as pre-formatted text in your question.

Comment: My only concern with posting my code is the input files are in the GB magnitude.  I believe I can post the pure code and relay anything to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the thumb drive I'm using is encrypted.  It outputs to /tmp/ so it's a permission thing.  That's the problem!

Answer (score 2):

For others encountering the same stupid error under cygwin in a script that works under a real Linux: no idea why, but it can happen:

1) after a syntax error in the script

2) because cygwin bash wants you to replace `./myScript.sh` with `. ./myScript.sh` (where dot is the bash-style include directive, aka `source`)